# Can be optimized?

Tags: c++-cli

can it be optimized and write it through the function? Thanks

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    textBox1->Clear();
    textBox2->Clear();
    textBox3->Clear();
    textBox4->Clear();
    textBox5->Clear();
    textBox6->Clear();
    textBox7->Clear();
    textBox8->Clear();
    textBox9->Clear();
    textBox10->Clear();
    textBox11->Clear();
    textBox12->Clear();
    textBox13->Clear();
    textBox14->Clear();
}
```

Comment: If you place your textBoxes in an collection you can iterate over it and call clear for each of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make std::vector and put all those textboxes in it. Then, you write a for loop and call Clear function on every element.